# How can I escape special characters in a PDO connection string?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I am using the PDO extension to connect to a MariaDB database from PHP.  I would like to know how to escape special characters for use in the connection string.

The obvious attempts (URL-encoding, enclosing in single quotes) all fail.

I currently don't need to connect to e.g. a strangely-named database, but I would like to know how in case I do.

Specifically: Suppose I have the following PHP code

```
<?php
$username = 'some user';
$password = 'some password';
$host = 'dummy.example.com';
$port = 1 << 16;
$dbname= 'alpha;a=b';
$PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname", 
                $username, $password, []);
```

This doesn't work because the semicolon in `$dbname` is interpreted as a metacharacter.  I would like to know how to escape this character.

Comment: did you try `$dbname= 'alpha\;a=b';` ?

Comment: i don't think that anyone, ever, would use special characters as a database name - if it is even allowed. at least - also, UTF-encoding and regular escaping should take care of this?

Comment: btw, variables don't get parsed in single quotes `'mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname'`. SooOOoooo `"mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname"`. Could be the clincher here.

Comment: well you can ping right? I've looked at the question long enough with no response from 2 comments. Gotta run. good luck :-)

Comment: @RyanVincent maybe *lol* I left the question and then you pulled me right back in *haha!*. Ok... now I'm really gone. *ciao*

Comment: @Fred I meant to use double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some, strange reason you need to do this, don't use the `dbname` parameter in the dns. Instead, use your database driver to select it for you:

```
$dbh->query('use "newdatabase"'); // for mysql.
```

This way, you have the option to enclose the database name with `"`, so you can name it *whatever the driver* **allows**. For MySQL for this specific scenario it is the `"` character, but that does not mean its different for PostgreSQL or Firebase.

But this method is not bulletproof, it only allows the PDO library to parse the DSN as normal as I don't *expect* the PDO library to cope with this unusual situation as its only purpose is to interact with as many drivers as possible.

Driver specific allowances should not take part in PDO, so you should really ask the driver for this, this way you can also check if the query fails to execute.

Answer (score 0):

A database, table, or column name can (and should in your case) be *quoted* with backtics (`alpha;a=b`).

But, that may not be sufficient.  `;` is an important character in several contexts; the backtics may not be sufficient.  The 'real fix' is to stick with letters, digits, and underscores in such names.

Xorifelse's answer points out a likely situation where the backtics won't suffice.